# How to properly structure class in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, architecture

I have a class called `TileStreamer` that I am currently defining as follows:

```
function TileStreamer {

};
```

This class has constants, which I define as follows:

```
// Tiles are 256 x 256 pixels 
TileStreamer.prototype.TILE_SIZE = 256; 

// Header size in bytes
TileStreamer.prototype.HEADER_SIZE = 28; 

// Various table entry sizes in bytes 
TileStreamer.prototype.RESOLUTION_ENTRY_SIZE = 12; 
TileStreamer.prototype.TILE_COUNT_SIZE = 4; 
TileStreamer.prototype.TILE_ENTRY_SIZE = 12; 

// Offsets within header 
TileStreamer.prototype.WIDTH_OFFSET = 3; 
TileStreamer.prototype.HEIGHT_OFFSET = 4; 
TileStreamer.prototype.NUM_TABLES_OFFSET = 7; 
TileStreamer.prototype.UNPOPULATED_OFFSET = 12092;
```

There also other variables.  These variables are important because **they need to be accessible from other classes**.  They get their values within the methods of this class.  This is what I am unsure of as far as structure. What I'm currently trying is:

```
TileStreamer.prototype.header; 
TileStreamer.prototype.resolutionEntry; 
TileStreamer.prototype.resolutionTable; 
TileStreamer.prototype.filepath; 
TileStreamer.prototype.s3; 
TileStreamer.prototype.level; 
TileStreamer.prototype.ncols; 
TileStreamer.prototype.nrows; 
TileStreamer.prototype.nlevels; 
TileStreamer.prototype.toffset; 
TileStreamer.prototype.tsize; 
TileStreamer.prototype.modifiedTime; 
TileStreamer.prototype.tile; 
TileStreamer.prototype.host; 
TileStreamer.prototype.bucket;
```

This class also has methods such as:

```
TileStreamer.prototype.Init = function(filepath, index, s3config){
   var retval = false; 
   AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: s3config.access_key, secretAccessKey: s3config.secret_key});
   var blc = new BlockLibraryConfigs(); 
   var awsConfig = blc.awsConfig; 
   AWS.config.update({region: awsConfig.region}); 

   var aws = new AWS.S3(); 
   var params = {
       Bucket: s3config.bucket, 
       Key: s3config.tile_directory + filepath, 
       Range: 'bytes=0-' + (this.HEADER_SIZE - 1)
   };

    aws.getObject(params, function(err, data){
       if(err == null){
            TileStreamer.modifiedTime = data.LastModified; 
            var header = bufferpack.unpack('<7I', data.Body);
            TileStreamer.header = header; 
            TileStreamer.nlevels = header[TileStreamer.NUM_TABLES_OFFSET]; 

            if(TileStreamer.nlevels == 5){
                TileStreamer.level = 0; 
                TileStreamer.ncols = Math.ceil((header[TileStreamer.WIDTH_OFFSET] * 1.0) / TileStreamer.TILE_SIZE); 
                TileStreamer.nrows = Math.ceil((header[TileStreamer.HEIGHT_OFFSET] * 1.0) / TileStreamer.TILE_SIZE);   

            }  
       }

    });     

};
```

The method above should set some of the values of the variables, such as `modifiedTime` so that I can access it in another class such as:

```
TileStreamer = require('tilestreamer.js'); 
var ts = new TileStreamer();
ts.Init(parPath, index, config); 
var last_modified = ts.modifiedTime;
```

Comment: The simplest way is to declare properties in the init function with the `this` prefix... https://jsfiddle.net/v6muohyk/

Comment: Was just going to say the same. use 'this' or TileStreamer.prototype.modifiedTime = ...;

Comment: @jjhavokk So when I need to set variables in an asynchronous function, as I do in my code, would using `TileStreamer.prototype.modifiedTime = data.LastModified` set `modifiedTime` for the same instance?

Comment: @tibsar it would be for all instances. If you will be managing many instances of TileStreamer then use 'this'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put any public properties you want to initialise when the object is created, directly in the init function.  Here's a small example...

```
function TileStreamer() {
};

TileStreamer.prototype.Init = function() {
    this.modifiedTime = new Date();
}; 

var ts = new TileStreamer();
ts.Init();
console.log(ts);
```

**jsfiddle example**

https://jsfiddle.net/v6muohyk/

To get around the issue you're having with setting the object properties in a callback from an asynchronous function, just create a locally accessible variable to reference the object that you are creating at that time...

```
TileStreamer.prototype.Init = function() {
    var thisTileStreamer = this;
    asynchFunction(function(err, data) {
        thisTileStreamer.modifiedTime = data.lastModified;
    });
};
```

To take it one step further, if you need to execute some code after the `init` function has completed, then that will require waiting for the asynchronous function to complete, as well.  For that, pass a further parameter to `init`, that is a function to be executed after all the work is done...

```
TileStreamer.prototype.Init = function(callback) {
    var thisTileStreamer = this;
    asynchFunction(function(err, data) {
        thisTileStreamer.modifiedTime = data.lastModified;
        callback();
    });
};

var ts = new TileStreamer();
ts.Init(function() {
    // put code here that needs to be executed *after* the init function has completed
    alert(ts.modifiedTime);
});
```

Comment: In my code, things such as the `modifiedTime` are set in an asynchronous function, so how would I set those?

Comment: I've added an extra bit to cover that.  The problem you were facing was that you had created an object and were then trying to set values for properties of the class.  So it wasn't a reference to the object that was being created.

Comment: Okay, trying it out.  So I should have access to the `thisTileStreamer` variable within the asynchronous function without passing it as a parameter?

Comment: Yes, it's within scope for the anonymous function.  As well as making it work, it makes it easier on the eye too :)

Comment: It looks like everything is working within the `TileStreamer` class, but I'm having issues accessing the variables from within another class.  I've tried  
`var TileStreamer = require('tilestreamer.js');  var ts = new TileStreamer(); ts.Init(parPath, index, config);  var date = ts.modifiedTime;`  but date is coming up as undefined

Comment: That's because the asynchronous function hasn't completed. Anything that is dependent on that function completing should be put inside the callback function, after the value is set, or pass another callback function to init, and execute that after all the values have been set.

Comment: I have things in another class that are dependent on that function finishing. How would I work with that?

Comment: If other classes require this one to be completely initialised then you must wait until it is before you create any instances of those classes.  Use the callback method to make sure this object is complete before continuing (I've added an example to the above code).

Comment: You're being super helpful! Just one more question! So this now passes in a callback as a parameter to `Init`, which makes sense, but do I need to then explicitly call the callback within `Init` or will it do it automatically upon completion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111006/discussion-between-archer-and-tibsar).